# Firebash Crashlytics without Google Play Services - Where to see the crash reports?

Tags: android, build.gradle, google-play-services, crashlytics

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services?hl=en), Google Play Services is not required for Firebase Crashlytics.
I added the dependencies to build.gradle (:app) like this:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0"))
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

I then added a button that throws an Exception when clicked. I installed the app and clicked the button and the app crashed, as expected.

However, when I open the Crashlytics tab in console.firebase.google.com, I cannot see a dashboard. I see the [Add SDK button](https://i.imgur.com/DnPfIsn.png), which leads to [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=en&platform=android), where it is not explained how to add Crashlytics to an app without adding Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow all the steps mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) to configure Crashlytics. Including the part of [adding Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to your Android project.

After doing this, try getting [debug logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable-debug-logging) if the same behavior continues. These logs can provide information on what could be going wrong.